# Set order of polygons to burn into a raster with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

I have intersecting polygons with an attribute that I'd like to burn into a raster with GDAL. In this simple example, the attribute `Value` from three polygons in one shapefile is to be transferred to a one-band raster. However, I have hundreds of polygons and they are not organised according to attribute values or location.

[image: intersecting polygons]

If I run gdal_rasterize:

> gdal_rasterize -ot Float32 -of gtiff -init -a Value -tr 1 1 -te -150 -150 150 150 -l test  test.shp test.tif

I get a nice raster:

[image: nice raster]

but my problem is that I want the highest value of any intersecting polygon to be burnt into the raster, not the last polygon.

**What is the easiest way to burn the highest attribute value into a raster, only using gdal/ogr?**

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/254758/2856

Comment: Thanks @Luke , this is probably the way to do it and a solution I didn't find. I guess that I could run the SQL command directly with gdal_rasterize? I'll give it a go.

Comment: The -sql option is even documented in http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html